# Xcode Version 15.2 (15C500b) | User Script Sandboxing: NO - Sandbox: rsync.samba(23853) deny(1) file-read-data

Tags: xcode

In the Xcode 15.2 version, I installed any pod framework to project. Then I tried the build but I received this error:

> Sandbox: rsync.samba(23853) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectname-hhxchyexdtsemtcslklrzltsqsjy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/projectname.app/Frameworks/MarqueeLabel.framework/MarqueeLabel.bundle

I did some research and found a solution;

Project Build Settings > Build Options > User Script Sandboxing = NO

Correct! There is no error.

[image]

Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Is your question asking why the error is fixed by changing that build setting?

Comment: Yes, I have no idea about this issue

Answer (score 0):

The value of `User Script Sandboxing` might have been changed from `NO` to `YES` if you agreed to have Xcode update your project to the recommended project settings.

I had the same problem with a Flutter App, recently.